# In php,how to a class has all methods of another class?

Tags: php

In php,I have two classes:

```
Class A
{
    public function a1()
    {
        ...
    }
    public function a2()
    {
        ...
    }

    more methods.

}
Class B
{
    private $b=new A();
}
```

I wanna B has all methods of class A.But I don't want to rewrite a1(),a2()... in class B.
It's too much trouble.Is there any better way?
Thanks.

I'm so sorry. I think my example code is not quite right.
The following is new class B:

```
class B
{
    private static $a=new A();
}
```

I'd like multiple instances of B share a instance of A.
So I think inheritance is not enough.
Thanks.

Comment: `Class B extends A`?

Comment: It's all in the official documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: "It's too much trouble" seemingly as is learning a little about PHP classes. Classes are a large learning curve, so would be worth while doing some extensive reading, then you can ask more specific questions suitable for SO.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `extends` when defining the class.

```php
<?php

Class A
{
    public function a1()
    {
        ...
    }
    public function a2()
    {
        ...
    }

    more methods.

}
Class B extends A
{
    public function a3() {
        $this->a1();
        $this->a2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Class B extends A
{
}
```

This is called inheritance.  Class B will inherit all the public and protected methods from its parent class A.

This is a well defined programming practice and I suggest you look into it further.  For a php reference look here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Answer (score -1):

```
class B {
  private $b
  function __construct() {
    $this->b = new A();
  }
}
```

Try the above

Or

```
class B extends A {
}
```

You can also checkout the following:

- http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipp4WPDwwvk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF0RicJb20da8nECQ1jFvla